# How to connect my iOS app on API .js

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

i'm sorry for my bad english but i'm french intern and noob on development iOS

I would like to connect my app with a login (login, password) on a web site almost created by my internship supervisor.
http://factomos.com

he gave me a API to make connection (he don't know objective C):
https://factomos.com/api/test/

I saw that it was necessary to use Web service (ex: AFNetworking POST to REST webservice) but it is about of .json then I need of .js 
I am lost, i need some help, i have not many times before the end of my internship.

Thank you very much
merci beaucoup

**edit**
I try this but not way

```
- (IBAction)logButton:(UIButton *)sender
```

{

```
NSString *username = loginTextField.text;

NSString *password = pwdTextField.text;

NSString *urlString = @"https://factomos.com/api/test/";
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": username, @"password": password};
[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if ([operation.responseString rangeOfString:@"You are logged in as"].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Bad login.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Login successful!");
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

}

Comment: Do you have the appropriate API keys that allow you access to the API?

Answer (score 1):

To further expand Stephen's answer, you can refer to the code here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#post-url-form-encoded-request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The parameters dictionary can be the username & password dictionary that you need to send to the API. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript in your iOS app. You need to get the data (using something like AFNetworking or the builtin NSURLSession) and then parse the information returned using something like `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API's without AFHTTP class
like this:

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache" };
NSMutableArray *parameters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"param1",@"param2", nil];
NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"value1",@"value2", nil];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
//NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0f); uncomment to post image
   NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

for (int i=0;i<parameters.count;i++) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",[parameters objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[values objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
NSLog(@"Parameters : %@",parameters);
NSLog(@"Values : %@",values);

//for image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"file.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImage]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your API URL here"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                 } else {
                     NSMutableArray *rowBtnTableLast2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                     rowBtnTableLast2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                     NSLog(@"PostMethod Result : %@ PostMethod Error : %@",rowBtnTableLast2,error);
                 }}];
[dataTask resume];
```